# How to make orderBy by the external table in Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have four tables: `projects`, `experiments`, `projects_experiments` and `projects_experiments_orders`

`projects_experiments_orders` table look like that:

`project_experiment_id | position`

How can I make ordering `experiments` by positions from the `experiments_orders` in Eloquent Laravel?

Comment: Is there any relationship?

Comment: Between `projects` and `experiments` - Many to Many in table `projects_experiments ` (id | project_id | experiment_id)

Comment: An `experiment` can have multiple `orders`. Which one do you want to use for ordering?

Comment: `experiment` can have only one `order`